# How to platform exception error flutter 2020

Tags: firebase, flutter, email, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get to get a dialog pop to indicate to the user that the email already exists, but I keep getting this error an the dialog pop doesn't show, have gone through similar solution but none seem to work  any help will be appreciated

> Exception has occurred.
> FirebaseAuthException ([firebase_auth/email-already-in-use] The email address is already in use by another account.)

Below is my authentication code

```
    void registerToFb() {
firebaseAuth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
    .then((result) {
  dbRef.child(result.user.uid).set({
    "email": emailController.text,
    "age": ageController.text,
    "name": nameController.text
  }).then((res) {
    isLoading = false;
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home(uid: result.user.uid)),
    );
  });
}).catchError((err) {
  print(err);
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Error"),
          content: Text(err.message),
          actions: [
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Ok"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      });
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've not checked the latest docs but I think the error codes have changed. First check by printing what's inside `err.message`. I read somewhere this changed to `err.code`!

Comment: Tried printing it but it won't even excite, it breaks the code and stop the entire execution and I need to restart the app again

Comment: tried that also, the error code gets attached to this (firebase_auth/email-already-in-use] The email address is already in use by another account. code:email-already-in-use)